# How To store a stack in onSaveInstanceState()?

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, lifecycle

I have a stack of `int`s in my `Activity`, but it gets empty when the screen rotates.
I searched a bit and find out `onSaveInstanceState` but it seems that I can't store the stack this way? it is just for primary variable types, right?
What should I do ? any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack is a class which implements Serializable interface.

So you can use

```
outState.putSerializable("stack", stack);
```

to store the stack in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) and retrieve the stack by

```
Stack<Integer> stack=(Stack<Integer>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("stack");
```